# Fancy Box Overlay not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, magento, fancybox

I am having an issue with FancyBox and IE8. For some reason IE8 does not recognize the background transparency on fancybox's overlay. It works in IE7 and older and Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

You can see the problem at: http://seabagsc.nexcess.net/tote-bags/kevlar-tote.html

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Chuck

Comment: I ended up removing the overlay soon after this post and never found the exact issue. I think it was limited to IE7 (And most likely IE6 (I don't even want to know what it looks like in IE6 :)))

Comment: A good solution here :
[fancybox-overlay-not-present-in-older-ie][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639902/fancybox-overlay-not-present-in-older-ie

Comment: An answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639902/fancybox-overlay-not-present-in-older-ie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639902/fancybox-overlay-not-present-in-older-ie

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but in case anyone runs across this, I ended up fixing my IE8 problems with FancyBox by setting

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

at the top of the page.  After that the overlay worked just fine.

Comment: I experienced something similar. Just so you know, if changing the Doctype worked for you then that's a symptom of badly structured HTML (like maybe you tag that isn't being closed somewhere.) In my experience when I don't close `<a>` tags then I experience issues like this where changing the Doctype somehow fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some issues in the past with FancyBox and IEx. Normally it's got something to do with freezing the browser tab when you have images on your page that are still loading. Since then, I've been using ColorBox, which is, IMO, a better alternative with fewer problems:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: I recommended the colorbox too!