# Fancybox not displaying correctly in IE8

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a site http://skidox.com and there is a little calendar on the left hand side. If you click one of the green boxes, the data shows in a fancybox correctly in all browsers except IE8.

I can't seem to figure out what why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try setting the `type` of content to `ajax` in your fancybox custom script

Comment: Ok I did this, but i'm unable to test in IE8 until Monday.

Comment: Adding type ajax did not work.

Comment: problem in your nivo slider js (line 22). i.e. nivoRun(slider,kids,settings,false), please correct it.

Comment: one question : you set dimensions in your fancybox custom script `width: 560` and `height: 340`, however fancybox is opening fitting the content (smaller) size. Do you want for any content to be 560x340 fixed? otherwise what is the idea behind setting width and height?

Comment: Good question, but I don't have a solid answer for you since i created this site like 2 years ago. If fancybox is auto sizing then that's just fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `</div>` at the end of your Ajax response. Try to remove it. IE8 is pretty sensitive for syntax errors.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where exactly is the extra `</div>` tag?

Comment: That extra div tag was causing the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When i changed the documentmode from ie 8 standards to standards on inspect element in ie, it works fine . that means document type issue. May be this will help you. Can you try this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875770/fancy-box-overlay-not-working-in-ie8)

Also I have seen in your site on ie 8 mode that, the doctype is not declared.

Comment: as far as I can see the OP has this `<!doctype html>` as first line of his html document (unless I am missing something)

Comment: The doctype is declared as JFK has pointed out. It's the html5 doctype.

Comment: I saying about on ie8 mode. can you please check these picture links -  [ie docment mode in standards](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/kzai.png/) and [ie docment mode in ie standards](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/571/ex0n.png/)

Comment: You can see the doctype as a commented line on ie document mode in ie standards.These pictures are screenshots of ie in **Browser Mode to IE8**.

Comment: I don't think that the doctype being commented is the issue because even google.com has it commented when viewing it in IE8 mode.

Comment: Even if i change the doctype to html-transitional it stills shows as a comment so that's not the issue.

Comment: IE7 shows exactly the same problem so I wouldn't say is a compatibility mode issue

Comment: No i'm still stuck on this problem.

Comment: May be I am wrong. But I strongly believe that it is a compatibility issue, because there is no issue with other browsers as you say and also ie9 and ie10 have no issues and even ie8 and ie7 again have no issues when document mode set to standards. (Sorry for asking-Did you check on ie7 and ie8 with document mode set to standards- I mean by setting it on inspect element.). Anyway I am also looking your issue and expects for a solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I once faced the same issue with fancybox and ie8 :

Try replacing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

with

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I saw that on another SO question and tried that already. Didn't seem to help. I just updated fancybox to fancybox 2 about an hour ago, but won't be on a windows box to test IE8 until Monday. Hoping it fixed the problem.